# Use `less` to view comma-aligned data

Tags: command-line, csv

I have a *big* CSV file.

I would like to view my file using `less` or some command like it which doesn't have to read the whole file at once to show me part of it.

Is there a command out there which can show me my file in comma-aligned columns?

Comment: I notice a problem here: you would like to have comma-aligned view, but at the same time wish that the program does not read the whole file... But to show the data correctly aligned, the program would **have** to read through the file to determine the maximum width of a column!

Comment: I thought of that, but I don't see that as being an impediment. Only a fixed part of a file is viewable at a time and I don't so much care if the columns adjust their size dynamically. Either that, or perhaps whatever this magic program is, you press a key and it realigns.

Comment: That is, @rozcietrzewiacz, that, for viewing purposes, only the local maxima are important. Especially if you remember the largest local maximum you've seen yet, which will tend towards the global maximum.

Comment: Cross posting? http://askubuntu.com/questions/57369/use-less-to-view-big-multi-gigabyte-csv-files

Comment: Indeed, @enzotib. I'd thought that this wasn't appropriate for stackoverflow originally, but other people pointing back there seemed to implicitly imply that it was.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if that is enough for you, but you could make use of `column` program and read the selected parts of the file using `head` and/or `tail` like this:

```
 head -n 300 myfile.csv | tail -n 100 | column -ts ',' | less
 head -n-300 myfile.csv | head -n 100 | column -ts ',' | less
```

You could wrap it up in some script to view different parts of the file at a time (probably without `less` then). Apart from that, I'm afraid it would be a problem to use only the GNU tools for the job.

Comment: In my experience, less doesn't try to read the whole file by default, so simply `colum -ts ',' myfile.csv | less` should work.

Comment: `less` obviously doesn't, but `column` does - so it's not a good solution after all...

Comment: See also 'man cut' to view only specific columns, e.g. `cut -d',' -f1,4-6` would return only columns 1,4,5 and 6

Answer (score 3):

Use `less` but when you want to see the CSV data column-aligned, pipe the current page through the `column -ts ,` command:

```
       | <m> shell-command
              <m>  represents  any  mark letter.  Pipes a section of the input
              file to the given shell command.  The section of the file to  be
              piped  is  between  the first line on the current screen and the
              position marked by the letter.   may also be ^ or $ to  indi-
              cate beginning or end of file respectively.  If  is . or new-
              line, the current screen is piped.

       m      Followed by any lowercase letter,  marks  the  current  position
              with that letter.
```

so use `|.column -ts ,` in `less`

Answer (score 2):

I've had good experience with [`tabview`](https://github.com/firecat53/tabview), though it does not always behave nicely with large files. However, in conjunction with `head` it's pretty decent.

Comment: This program is amazing. I can't accept this answer because I was asking about large files, but I'd upvote more if I could :-)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a unixy question, but in any case, I'd recommend using something different from `less` for viewing csv files. It isn't really the right tool. Try something like `R`, which has good support for looking at and if necessary, working with CSV files. E.g. to read 5 rows of a csv file, do

```
$ R
> read.csv("pheno.csv",nrows=5)
  faid   expid pid mid sex pheno
1 1420 NA12003   0   0   1     0
2 1420 NA12004   0   0   2     0
3 1420 NA10838   9  10   1     0
4 1420 NA12005   0   0   1     0
5 1420 NA12006   0   0   2     0
```

See

```
> help(read.csv)
```

for help. See also

```
> help(write.csv)
```

for writing to a file etc.

EDIT: I happened to have a csv file which is 1.1G and is 934991 lines long.

```
$ time Rscript -e 'read.csv("GenomeWideSNP_6.na29.annot.csv", skip=500000, nrows=5, header=FALSE)'
```

This skips 500,000 lines and reads 5 lines. R takes 1 minute to return this, and tops out at 620M usage (!) It looks like it may be reading the skipped lines into memory, though that makes no sense.

The upshot: I'm not really an R fan, but for handling small to medium data sets, especially if you want to do statistical analyses on it, you could do worse than R. 
An alternative is Python and some csv processing library.

Comment: R may be wonderful but is it the right tool for simply viewing the middle 20 rows of a 100,000 row CSV file? The question sought a program that didn't first load the whole file into memory.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Reasonable point. See added example. R's memory usage in this case is nuts. For this reason, if memory usage was a concern, Python or Perl might be better. They would also probably be faster.